# Create RDLC file by script with defined DataSource as collection

Tags: c#, .net, xml, reporting-services, rdlc

how can I define dataset as Object list (dictionary) inside XML RDLC file?
I want create this rdlc reports in script...
Something like this, is somewhere in internet any example?

```
<DataSources>
  <DataSource Name="DataSource">
    <ConnectionProperties>
      <DataProvider>System.Collections.Generic.List<CoolClass></DataProvider>
    </ConnectionProperties>
  </DataSource>
</DataSources>
<DataSets>
  <DataSet Name="DataSet">
    <Query>
      <DataSourceName>DataSource</DataSourceName>
    </Query>
  </DataSet>
</DataSets>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a list of objects in a report you'll have to generate the XSD for it in the report designer.  I'm not sure how to do it directly with XML but here's how the data set looks after I generated it from the object types.

```
<rd:DataSetName>EDIStagingDataSet</rd:DataSetName>        
  <rd:SchemaPath>C:\Projects\Reports\ObjectDataSet.xsd</rd:SchemaPath>
  <rd:TableName>ObjectList</rd:TableName>
  <rd:TableAdapterFillMethod>Fill</rd:TableAdapterFillMethod>
  <rd:TableAdapterGetDataMethod>GetData</rd:TableAdapterGetDataMethod>
  <rd:TableAdapterName>EDIShipmentItemsTableAdapter</rd:TableAdapterName>
</rd:DataSetInfo>
```